# mySQL report to only show negative results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running the mySQL report below, but only want negative values for the variance to show. I have tried putting a check in the "where" clause, but since the variance is created on the fly, it does not seem like that is a possibility. I have also tried using "having", but it errors out. I am assuming it is something simple that I am just missing. Please help.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.PUBLISHER SEPARATOR '\n') 
             AS Publisher, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.NAME SEPARATOR '\n') 
             AS 'Product',
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.MAJOR_VERSION SEPARATOR '\n') 
             AS 'Version',
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.CATEGORY SEPARATOR '\n') 
             AS 'Category',
       SUM(DISTINCT FIELD_1) AS 'Licenses',
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.INSTALLED_ON SEPARATOR '\n') 
             AS 'Installed',
       SUM(DISTINCT FIELD_1) - GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.INSTALLED_ON     SEPARATOR '\n') 
             AS 'Variance'
FROM SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE 
  LEFT JOIN SAM_VIEW_MACHINE_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE 
            ON SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.ID = SAM_VIEW_MACHINE_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.ID
  LEFT JOIN MACHINE 
            ON MACHINE.ID = SAM_VIEW_MACHINE_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.MACHINE_ID 
  LEFT JOIN ASSET_CATALOG_ASSOCIATION 
            ON ASSET_CATALOG_ASSOCIATION.ASSOCIATED_CATALOG_ID = SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.ID 
  LEFT JOIN ASSET 
            ON ASSET.ID = ASSET_CATALOG_ASSOCIATION.ASSET_ID 
  LEFT JOIN ASSET_DATA_7 
            ON ASSET_DATA_7.ID = ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID 
  LEFT JOIN ASSET_FIELD_DEFINITION 
            ON ASSET_FIELD_DEFINITION.ID = ASSET_CATALOG_ASSOCIATION.ASSET_FIELD_ID
WHERE FIELD_1 > 0 
GROUP BY SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.ID 
ORDER BY PUBLISHER, CATEGORY
```

Comment: Change it to HAVING (which would come after GROUP BY)

Comment: whre did you put HAVING clause and what was the error?

Comment: You definitely need table name aliases for this query!

Comment: What is `SUM(DISTINCT FIELD_1) - GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SAM_VIEW_DISCOVERED_SOFTWARE.INSTALLED_ON SEPARATOR '\n')` supposed to do?  `SUM()` returns an integer, `-` is the subtraction operator, and `GROUP_CONCAT()` returns a varchar of what appears to be a datetime field.  `15 - '2015-01-01 00:00:00\n2014-12-01 00:00:00'` is not a valid operation as far as I'm aware.